# changing JSON object values with javascript function inputs

Tags: javascript

I am completing a [freeCodeCamp exercise](http://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/checkpoint-record-collection#?solution=%2F%2F%20Setup%0Avar%20collection%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%202548%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20album%3A%20%22Slippery%20When%20Wet%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20artist%3A%20%22Bon%20Jovi%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20tracks%3A%20[%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Let%20It%20Rock%22%2C%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22You%20Give%20Love%20a%20Bad%20Name%22%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20]%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%202468%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20album%3A%20%221999%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20artist%3A%20%22Prince%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20tracks%3A%20[%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%221999%22%2C%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Little%20Red%20Corvette%22%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20]%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%201245%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20artist%3A%20%22Robert%20Palmer%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20tracks%3A%20[%20]%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%205439%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20album%3A%20%22ABBA%20Gold%22%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%2F%2F%20Keep%20a%20copy%20of%20the%20collection%20for%20tests%0Avar%20collectionCopy%20%3D%20JSON.parse%28JSON.stringify%28collection%29%29%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F%20Only%20change%20code%20below%20this%20line%0Afunction%20update%28id%2C%20prop%2C%20value%29%20%7B%0A%20%20if%28value%20!%3D%3D%20%22%22%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20collection[id][prop]%20%3D%20value%3B%0A%20%20%20%20if%28prop%20%3D%3D%20%22tracks%22%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20collection[id][prop].push%28value%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20collection[id][prop]%20%3D%20%22%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20return%20collection%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%2F%2F%20Alter%20values%20below%20to%20test%20your%20code%0Aupdate%285439%2C%20%22artist%22%2C%20%22ABBA%22%29%3B%0A%0A) and I've hit a dead end.

The purpose of the exercise is to write a function that takes 3 arguments (`id, prop, value`).

After some evaluation (check if prop is not blank, check if prop is "tracks"), the function should change the JSON object predefined (a record collection).

Running my code, I get some curious results. The wrong JSON properties get updated, or they do not get updated at all. I suspect that the problem is with the object calling, but I can't figure out what I did wrong. Any help is appreciated.

```
// Setup
var collection = {
    2548: {
      album: "Slippery When Wet",
      artist: "Bon Jovi",
      tracks: [ 
        "Let It Rock", 
        "You Give Love a Bad Name" 
      ]
    },
    2468: {
      album: "1999",
      artist: "Prince",
      tracks: [ 
        "1999", 
        "Little Red Corvette" 
      ]
    },
    1245: {
      artist: "Robert Palmer",
      tracks: [ ]
    },
    5439: {
      album: "ABBA Gold"
    }
};
// Keep a copy of the collection for tests
var collectionCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(collection));

// Only change code below this line
function update(id, prop, value) {
  if(value !== "") {
    if(prop == "tracks") {
      collection[id][prop].push(value);
    }
    else {
      collection[id][prop] = "";
    }
    collection[id][prop] = value;
  }

  return collection;
}

// Alter values below to test your code
update(5439, "artist", "ABBA");
```

I've also created a [codepen](http://codepen.io/shooshte/pen/dGvZxK) with the same code if anyone wants to tinker.

Comment: your codepen is different ... in it you say `collection[id][prop] = prop;` ... twice ... instead of `collection[id][prop] = value;` ... and in this code, you set `collection[id][prop] = "";` for anything other than "tracks" ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want something like

```
function update(id, prop, value) {
  if(value !== "") {
    collection[id] = collection[id] || {}; // to create id if required
    if(prop == "tracks") {
      collection[id].tracks = collection[id].tracks || []; // create empty tracks array if required
      collection[id].tracks.push(prop);
    }
    else {
      collection[id][prop] = value;
    }
  }

  return collection;
}
```

The above allows you to create a new id, and it handles adding the FIRST track properly

Answer (score 1):

this worked

```
function updateRecords(id, prop, value) {
    if(value == ""){
      delete collection[id][prop];
    }
    else if(prop == "tracks" && collection[id][prop]!= undefined){
      collection[id].tracks.push(value);
    }
    else if(prop != "tracks" && collection[id][prop]== undefined)
    {
      collection[id][prop] = value;
    }else if(prop == "tracks" && collection[id][prop]== undefined)
    {
      collection[id]["tracks"] = [];
      collection[id].tracks.push(value);
    }

      return collection;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Walk through the different cases (`prop` is `tracks` or not, `value` is `""` or not, so a total of 4 cases), and you'll see your logic is flawed. In your current code, if the value is not empty, you'll overwrite the property with the new value, whether it was an array or not.

It's not clear from your description what you actually want to do in all 4 cases (most particularly in the case when `value` is empty: should it overwrite things, do nothing...? Should it be different for the `tracks` array or not?), so it's difficult to suggest code, but if you write down what you want in all four cases, it's then easy to write the appropriate code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
    function update(id, prop, value) {
     if(value !== "") {
        collection[id] = collection[id] || {}; // to create id if required
        if(prop == "tracks") {
          collection[id].tracks = collection[id].tracks || []; // create empty tracks array if required
          collection[id].tracks.push(prop);
        } else {
          collection[id][prop] = value;   
       } }else {

    if (collection[id][prop].hasOwnProperty())  {   

    } else {
          delete collection[id][prop];
      }
     }

  return collection;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually had this same problem and had an issue with the code.  It passed the bulk of the test, but errored out trying to create a new property when there were no tracks.  I got this code to function instead:

```
function updateRecords(id, prop, value) {
  if((value !== "") && (prop !== "tracks")) {
    console.log("Updating or setting property: ", prop);
    console.log("setting property to: ", value);
    collection[id][prop] = value;
  }
  else if((value !== "") && (prop === "tracks")) {
    collection[id].tracks = collection[id].tracks || [];
    collection[id].tracks.push(value);
  }
  else if(value === "") {
    delete collection[id][prop];
  }

  return collection;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

**There is whole description:**

Write a function which takes an album's id (like 2548), a property prop (like "artist" or "tracks"), and a value (like "Addicted to Love") to modify the data in this collection.

If prop isn't "tracks" and value isn't blank, update or set the value for that record album's property.

Your function must always return the entire collection object.

There are several rules for handling incomplete data:

If prop is "tracks" but the album doesn't have a "tracks" property, create an empty array before adding the new value to the album's corresponding property.

If prop is "tracks" and value isn't blank, push the value onto the end of the album's existing tracks array.

If value is blank, delete that property from the album.